# Bleach OST in episode 174 around 2:43

Tags: music, bleach

There's a song in episode 174 of *Bleach* from 2:43.

I couldn't find anywhere on YouTube/Google, even after I checked all the soundtrack lists.

What is this song?

Comment: Hey, welcome to A&M. We do not condone piracy, hence I have removed this part of your question. Also there is no need to curse, it's just not polite. While you wait for an answer, I would suggest you [take a tour](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a bit more familiar with how A&M works. And once again, welcome!

Comment: Always try Russian youtube. That seems to, for some reason, have more help for finding anime soundtracks than English versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unreleased OST called *Soul Society* by *Bleach*'s music producer, Shiro Sagisu ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gntBKXOrppI)).

Quote from OP:

> I found it. Can't believe I found it. It was so hard that even in the comments people say that found it by mistake and was not on purpose. I spent 5 years looking for this and I found it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gntBKXOrppI (YT: #10) BLEACH OST - Shiro Sagisu - BL_93 (Soul Society)) for anyone in my position